# Get current line in Sublime Text 3 plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a simple plugin for Sublime Text 3 and need to get the contents of the currently selected line.
I can use

```
selection = sublime.Region(self.view.sel()[0].begin(), self.view.sel()[0].end())
```

to get the currently highlighted section, but is there a way to select or return the contents of the entire current line without manually selecting all of it?

The 'duplicate' example on [this page](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples) does what I want, but seems to be broken in ST3.  When I run it I get the error `TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'`.

Comment: [the api](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe what you're after is `view.substr(view.line(view.sel()[0]))`

This will return the text of the current line.

Comment: I believe you're right, sir!  Thanks for that.  I had to add `self` before each `view...` though, so it became `self.view.substr(self.view.line(self.view.sel()[0]))`